# How to dynamically generate div in Vue?

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, vuejs2

I have the following code:

```
<div class="content">
    <p>Hello World</p>
</div>
```

And I have the following div count:

```
data() {
    return {
        divs: 2
    }
}
```

So, if `divs` is `2` then it should generate two divs and wrap the `div.content` inside it so it becomes something like this:

```
<div>
    <div>
        <div class="content">
            <p>Hello World</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

As you can see there's two divs and then only there's this `div.content`! I tried using `v-for` but it generates 2 separate divs! Please help!

Comment: What exactly you are trying to do ? and why ? Can you share more details with multiple data ?

Comment: @C2486 Well, my requirement is do to that way

Comment: @C2486 There's a sample data there!

Comment: what if `divs: 3` ?

Comment: @C2486 Then it will render three divs and only after that `div.content` should render

Comment: I suggest you to store your data as html so that you can display as `v-html` and you can easily change your html before storing.

Comment: @C2486 Can you provide a demo based on `divs: 2`?

Comment: It really looks interesting requirements from your side. I given my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*First off: this sounds like a pretty unnecessary requirement and most probably re-framing the problem will lead to a much better solution!*

That being said, there is a way to achieve what you're trying to do with some dark Vue magic ;-)

What you need is a recursive render function:

```
render: function (createElement) {
return this.level >= 1 ? 
  createElement('div', [createElement(DynamicDiv, {
    props: {
      level: this.level-1
    }
  }, this.$slots.default)]) : 
  createElement('div', this.$slots.default)
},
props: {
  level: {
    type: Number,
    required: true
  }
}
```

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/render-function.html

You can find a working example over here: https://codesandbox.io/s/k9p16wzmyo

Answer (score 1):

Here is the example to make multiple Div provided in vue data. with vue components.

```js
Vue.config.devtools = false;
Vue.config.productionTip = false;

Vue.component('my-div', {
  props:['mydata','divs'],
  template: '<div class="test"><div v-if="divs==1" class="text-center">{{mydata}}</div><div v-if="divs>1"><my-div :mydata="mydata" :divs="divs-1"></my-div></div></div>'
})

var v = new Vue({
el: '#app',
data:{
  name:'Niklesh Raut',
  divs:4
}
});
```

```css
#app div.test{
 border: 2px solid blue;
 padding:5px;
}
.text-center{
  text-align:center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <my-div :mydata="name" :divs="divs"></my-div>
</div>
```

Comment: That is a great answer.